# calculate ratios for every 2 columns in a data frame

Tags: r

I'm new to R, so this question maybe very simple to many of you. I have a data frame with 1000 columns, and 1000 rows, a bit like the follow

```
id  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
A1  2   7   9   56  34  23
A2  3   5   11  4   8   56
A3  8   22  32  45  67  76
A4  4   21  23  1   34  43
A5  6   12  5   19  36  46
A6  45  89  76  87  75  78
A7  45  71  56  65  34  87
A8  26  76  67  87  65  65
```

I'd like to get the ratio of column 1/2, column 3/4, ...column 999/1000, and then put in a matrix. I tried using "for" to do it, but never succeeded. Anyone can help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share what you tried with your `for` loop?

Comment: sorry, the data frame is look like this:

Comment: You might want to think about what happens if you have an odd number of columns.

Answer (score 9):

No need to use `for`, use `seq` to create an index for selecting the columns in the numerator and denominator

```
> num <- seq(2,ncol(df),2)  # index for numerator
> dem <- seq(3,ncol(df),2)  # index for denominator
> df[, num] / df[, dem]
         S1         S3        S5
1 0.2857143  0.1607143 1.4782609
2 0.6000000  2.7500000 0.1428571
3 0.3636364  0.7111111 0.8815789
4 0.1904762 23.0000000 0.7906977
5 0.5000000  0.2631579 0.7826087
6 0.5056180  0.8735632 0.9615385
7 0.6338028  0.8615385 0.3908046
8 0.3421053  0.7701149 1.0000000
```

All in one shot:  `df[,seq(2,ncol(df),2)] / df[, seq(3,ncol(df),2)]`

Comment: +1 I see that I basically did the exact same thing as you. But don't you want your `dem` to start from `1`?

Comment: no, because the first column of `df` is not numeric, it's a factor variable, that's why I rule out col1.

Comment: @Jilber there you go, I made up my own data rather than use the OP. Nice one for paying attention!