# Make data frame with ratios of every column against every other

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

This is similar to but not exactly the same as: [calculate ratios for every 2 columns in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385825/calculate-ratios-for-every-2-columns-in-a-data-frame/19386015#19386015)

I have a data frame where I want to make a ratio of every column versus every other (in one direction is okay, I don't need both.)

```
df <- bind_cols(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(2, 3, 4), z = c(3, 4, 5))

ratios_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(x_y = x/y,
         x_z = x/z,
         y_z = y/z) %>% 
  select(-c(x:z))
```

How can I make a more automated approach to generating ratios_df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- bind_cols(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(2, 3, 4), z = c(3, 4, 5))

df_ratios <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) x/df))
df_ratios
# x.x       x.y       x.z      y.x y.y       y.z      z.x      z.y z.z
# 1   1 0.5000000 0.3333333 2.000000   1 0.6666667 3.000000 1.500000   1
# 2   1 0.6666667 0.5000000 1.500000   1 0.7500000 2.000000 1.333333   1
# 3   1 0.7500000 0.6000000 1.333333   1 0.8000000 1.666667 1.250000   1

df_ratios <- df_ratios[, sapply(strsplit(colnames(df_ratios), "\\."), function(x) x[1] > x[2])]
# y.x      z.x      z.y
# 1 2.000000 3.000000 1.500000
# 2 1.500000 2.000000 1.333333
# 3 1.333333 1.666667 1.250000
```

Comment: Nice and simple! How about cleaning that up to only have unique relationships? I don't need reciprocal (like x/z and z/x) nor do I need identities(x/x).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `combn` to combine the columns together and then divide the first with the second:

```
combn(df, 2, function(x) x[[1]] / x[[2]])
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
[2,] 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.7500000
[3,] 0.7500000 0.6000000 0.8000000
```

You can add the names too:

```
nam = combn(names(df),2,paste,collapse="_")
`colnames<-`(combn(df,2,function(x)x[[1]]/x[[2]]),nam)
           x_y       x_z       y_z
[1,] 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
[2,] 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.7500000
[3,] 0.7500000 0.6000000 0.8000000
```

Comment: I had no idea you could pass a data.frame directly to `combn` like this (+1). Is this behaviour documented?  help(combn) suggests that x should be a vector, which is the typical usage.

Comment: I do pass lists. never read the documentation though. With the argument `simplify=F` you can be able to see how the passed object is combined. That will enable you know how to manipulate it

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `combn` to create the combination first and then do the calculations:

```
combos <- combn(names(df), 2, simplify = FALSE)

l2 <- lapply(combos, function(x) df[[ x[1] ]] / df[[ x[2] ]])

ratios_df <- setNames(as.data.frame(l2), sapply(l, paste, collapse = '_'))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > ratios_df
>         x_y       x_z       y_z
> 1 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
> 2 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.7500000
> 3 0.7500000 0.6000000 0.8000000
> ```